# HttpTestingController.expectOne() with queryparameters

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular testing using Jasmine/Karma. I encountered a problem while testing an angular service using `HttpTestingController`. Here is a part of the source code :

```js
getProfile(userName: string) {
    let config = {
      params: {
        user_id: "test"    
      }
    }
    return this.http
      .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${userName}`, config);
  }
```

when calling the service using `expectOne` of `HttpTestingController` :

```
it('should add an Authorization header', () => {
let response;
userService.getProfile('blacksonic').subscribe(response => {
  expect(response).toBeTruthy();    });


const req = 
httpMock.expectOne({ method: 'GET', url:'https://api.github.com/users/blacksonic' });
                   });
```

I get the following error :

```
Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match method: GET, URL: https://api.github.com/users/blacksonic", found none.
at HttpClientTestingBackend.expectOne (./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http/testing.js?:301:19)
at UserContext.eval (./src/app/Interceptors/Interceptor.spec.ts?:85:28)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:387:26)
at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:287:39)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:386:32)
at Zone.run (./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:137:43)
at runInTestZone (./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:508:34)
at UserContext.eval (./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:523:20)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you are passing a parameter. So something like this will work:

```
const req = httpMock.expectOne(
 { method: 'GET', url:'https://api.github.com/users/blacksonic?user_id=test' });
```

Comment: i even test this case but it is not working , same error.

Comment: problem solved by replacing :

`const req = 
httpMock.expectOne({ method: 'GET', url:'https://api.github.com/users/blacksonic' });`;

by  
`const req = httpMock.expectOne( (req: HttpRequest<any>)  => req.urlWithParams == "https://api.github.com/users/blacksonic?user_id=test");`